# JQuery & Team Visitor permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, jquery

Problem:  jQuery undefined if user logs in and is put with 'Team Site Visitor' group.  If I change the user to be in 'Team Site Member' group the jQuery gets loaded correctly and all subsequent custom js files work.

Does anyone have any clues why these roles/groups have any impact of jquery libraries being loaded?

Libraries are referenced in the associated aspx page for masterpages. So the page structure is kind of like this (found-4.3.2-server.master -> found4-orbit.aspx).  In the found4-orbit.aspx page I have this reference for google cdn

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All works really well if a person had edit features which are OOB for groups 'Team Site Member' and 'Team Site Owner' however I can't have my users in these groups.  They should be read only.

EDIT:
I have looked at the contribute 'Site Permissions' to see if I can understand what could cause such an issue.

EDIT: Curiosity told me to change the 'Read' permissions one by one to see if I can get the jQuery to load.  And yes I can.... If I set the 'List Permissions' as per screen shot

[image]

So why does the 'Edit Items' have influence on the loading of scripts?

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 0):

If you're jQuery file is in a document library, ensure that Team Site Visitors have atleast Read permissions for that document library and also ensure that the jQuery file is checked-in and published (if needed).

Comment: AH!  Sorry.  The jquery is referenced to google cdn.  A few articles I have read have mentioned that this isn't the way to go and that I should bring the jquery lib through to SP document library...

Comment: @ScottWhite Could you please update your question to include where and how you reference jQuery.

Comment: sure. will do it now